# Why boolean/char fields in One2many disappear if they have an attrs in Odoo 8?

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I have just found an error I am not able to fix. I have a transient model (I think the problem would arise even though the model were not transient) which has an `One2many` field. This field points to other model which has two `Boolean` fields (named `yes`, `no`) and a `Char` field (named `other_ans`). All of them have an `attrs` attribute in XML:

```
<field name="questions" nolabel="1">
    <tree editable="1" create="false">
        <field name="name" readonly="1"/>
        <field name="answer_type" readonly="1"/>
        <field name="yes" attrs="{'readonly': [('answer_type', '!=', 'boolean')]}"/>
        <field name="no" attrs="{'readonly': [('answer_type', '!=', 'boolean')]}"/>
        <field name="other_ans" attrs="{'readonly': [('answer_type', '!=', 'text')]}"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

The problem: I open the form, click on a button which fills in the `One2many` with several records, and then I start clicking on each record of the `One2many`, modifying the fields `yes`, `no` or `other_ans`. It starts working well, but after a time (totally random), all of a sudden, and just after clicking on `yes`, `no` or `other_ans`, these fields disappear from the current record, and I cannot check them or fill in them anymore, because when I click on other record, they appear again in the last selected record, but disappear from the current one. However, if I click about three times on any `other_ans` field which is not readonly (if there is someone), the fields appear again magically, and if I continue working, the problem appears again.

The problem stops if I remove `attrs` from these three fields (`yes`, `no`, `other_ans`) in the XML code. But I need it to prevent users from answer *yes* or *no* to a question which requires a text answer and the other way around.

Did anyone experience the same problem?